# Trouble with saving of cookies with CORS fields on response

Tags: javascript, python, cookies, angular5

please help to find the issue with cookies. Angular is getting needed data and looks like everything is working, but if I adding needed for Angular fields (Access-Control-Allow-Origin and Access-Control-Allow-Headers) the cookies is stopping work and browser is not saving them.. why? 
HTTP response is generating by my Python server with the next text (ex) :

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json
Set-Cookie: session=127578629; Domain=host1.com; expires=Mon, 25-Dec-2017 17:41:16 GMT
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, *
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true

"{logged:True}"
```

And Angular correctly gets this json also...
Thank you everyone for any tips... because i'm out of ideas...

P.S. Without CORS fields cookies is working wel...

Angular code (if required) :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  public apiURL:string = 'http://host1.com:9999/';
  public logged: boolean;
  response: any;

  constructor(private elementRef:ElementRef, private http:Http) {
        this.logged = this.elementRef.nativeElement.getAttribute('auth');
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.checkLogin()
  }

  checkLogin() {
    this.response = this.http.post(this.apiURL, {"search": "search"}).map(res => res.json()).subscribe(data => {console.log(data);});
  }

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by the *cookies stops working*? Can you please share your angular code as well?

Comment: I mean cookies is not setting anymore.. but angular is responding correctly

Comment: In the code you posted, you are not setting the cookies anywhere. By saying *setting cookies*, do you mean storing it the browser?

Comment: sorry for the not correctly text.. yes, in browser. I mean in console from Angular I see this json message, but cookies is not storing like before... (without CORS fields)

Comment: Could you please show how you are storing the cookies in Angular? You can edit the question.